# Diferential Equation by Laplace: $y'=-\frac{y}{ay+b}+S$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes

Hello and thanks for reading.

I wish to check the stability of the ODE

$$
y'=-\frac{y}{ay+b}+S
$$

by applying the limit theorem of Laplace, where $a$, $b$ and $S$ are real. After some algebra I have:

$$
ay'y+by'-aSy-bS+y=0.
$$

When I do Laplace transformation then I have to $L(y'y)$ and can't go on. I need the Laplace expression of $y$.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Thanks caverac for editing

Comment: Are you interested in using [de Moivre-Laplace theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%E2%80%93Laplace_theorem)? Or a Laplace transformation to solve for $y$?

Comment: Thanks for your time caverac. I really want a function for the final value for $y(t=\inf)$ dependant of $a$ $b$ and $ S $. I thought to use Laplace because the ODE seems easy, but it isn't to me. The rule I want to use is to find the expresion of $Y(s)$ and $lim$ $ s->0 Y(s)=lim$ $t-> \inf y(t)$

A time solution of the ODE also is helpfull

Comment: No demostration is needed, I will check the formula with my solver. Just I want the formula for $y(t)$ or $Y(s)$

Comment: For future reference, if you want to address a particular user, please use their name, i.e. `@JPS`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The asymptotic behavior of $y(t)$ for $t \to \infty$ can be qualitatively modeled without the need of an explicit solution of the ODE:

$$
\frac{{\rm d}y}{{\rm d}t} = -\frac{y}{ay + b} + S\tag{1}
$$

First of all, consider two cases

> **CASE 1:** $\color{red}{a=0}$

In this situation (1) becomes

$$
y(t) = -\frac{y}{b} +S
$$

whose solution is

$$
y(t)= b S+(y(0) - b) e^{-t/b}
$$

So you have two cases

> $a = 0$, $b > 0$

$$
\lim_{t\to \infty}y(t) = bS
$$

regardless of the initial condition $y(0)$

> $a = 0$, $b < 0$

$$
\lim_{t\to \infty}y(t) = +\infty
$$

regardless of the initial condition $y(0)$.

The case $a=0$, $b=0$ I will not consider because it leads to problems from the beginning.

> **CASE 2:** $\color{red}{a\not=0}$

If this is case I can call $t' = t/a$, $b' = b/a$ and $S' = Sa$ so that the (1) becomes

$$
\frac{{\rm d}y}{{\rm d}t'} = -\frac{y}{y + b'} + S' \tag{2}
$$

Intuitively speaking, if the RHS of this equation is 0, then the solution does not evolve from there. If it is larger than zero the solution grows, and decreases with time otherwise. So let us consider the situation

$$
-\frac{y^*}{y^* + b'} + S' = 0 ~~~\Rightarrow y^* = \frac{S'b'}{1 - S'} 
 = \frac{Sb}{1 - aS} \tag{3}
$$

If $y(0) = y^*$  it means that $y(t) = y(0)$ and

$$
\lim_{t\to \infty}y(t) = \frac{Sb}{1 - aS}
$$

In general we can expand $f(y)$ around the point $y^*$

$$
y = f(y^*) + \left.\frac{{\rm d}f}{\rm d y}\right|_{y = y^*}(y - y^*) + \cdots
$$

If we cal $\zeta = y - y^*$, at first order this equation implies

$$
\frac{{\rm d}\zeta}{\rm d t} = \alpha \zeta(t) ~~~\mbox{with}~~~ \alpha = \left.\frac{{\rm d}f}{\rm d y}\right|_{y = y^*} = \frac{(a S - 1)^2}{b}
$$

There are a few cases to consider here

> $S \not= 1 /a$, $b > 0$

For this case $d\zeta/dt > 0$, if $\zeta > 0$, which means that the separation between $y$ and $y^*$ grows exponentially.

The rest of the analysis I will leave for you to finish

Comment: Thank you very much carevac. My bad $a$ is not $0$. I'm in that case. I was looking for this $\lim_{t\to \infty}y(t) = \frac{Sb}{1 - aS}$

The equation is for the behavior of a chemical reactor where $y$ is the concentration of the reactive and $S$ the feeding of new reactive.
I have checked the equation and it works perfectly.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: @JPS After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/).